# Repair (fixing back) lifted power thru hole pad + trace

Tags: repair, pad

Attached pictures are a lifted power pad + trace of a 1000 W PSU of a commercial subwoofer. Caliper showed 0.42 mm thick, which if correct gives about 12 oz copper trace!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In this particular pad was the source of a MOSFET after a rectifier bridge, transformer and capacitor bank.

Pad + trace are intact, I just need to reliably fix them back to place.

What are the best options? Epoxy? Maybe araldite? I am not sure if it will ever corrode copper or sensitive electronics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Epoxy should be a great choice. I would tape the back of the circuit board so that the epoxy can go in the hole and self-level, put the epoxy in, and then use tape to hold the trace down.

After that, you'll need to re-drill the hole for the replacement component. The existing hole was probably plated through; if it was, you will need to solder the component onto both the top and bottom traces.

Comment: Mechanically I also think one can't go better. Now, are you sure that epoxy won't corrode anything?

Comment: @tfm it looks like the vias have separated also. you may need to feed a wire through and solder it on both sides after you're done.

Comment: Folks, anybody else? Epoxy corroding copper or electronics?