# Finding datasheet for this MOSFET! (SMS5408 0932)

Tags: mosfet

This component carries the markings SMS5408 0932 is busted! It is part of a 1000W psu of a flagship subwoofer of a (very) respectable brand, and I can't find any datasheet at all for it!

[image]
[image]

I assume it is a MOSFET because of the G,D and S markings on PCB. Only thing I could find for the SMS was this company:

http://www.siliconmicrosystems.co.uk/contact.html

that seems to provide asic services, doesn't seem to manufacture components. Also couldn't find any reference for 5408 except diodes.

Usual websites like alldatasheet, datasheetcatalog, etc didn't bring anything up. Contacting the manufacturer is no good, they've sent me another unit so no one would have to worry about repairing anything. But I really won't let this off because I can't find a replacing mosfet!! ;)

New image (PCB backside):

[image: PCB backside]

Comment: Looks like the S pad is torn apart. Are you sure the board would accept a new transistor?

Comment: Did you look at the replacement unit? It might have more useful markings.

Comment: I wasn't able to track that part down, either. But you may take into consideration that it may be an IGBT. This depends on currents and voltages used in the circuitry. Do you have any knowledge about these values?

Comment: Hrm, this is a tough one; 5408 appears one of the most overused ids/numbers in electronics history: there's 2SC5408 (a NEC NPN transistor), 2N5408, 1N5408 none of which make sense in this application...

Comment: There's also a NTE5408, a SCR, but I can't see how it would work here. Also BA5408 is some power amp and AmericanMicroSemi's S5408 is some logic gate. Eww...

Comment: NTD5407/STD5407 (by On Semi) is actually a MOSFET but in DPAK. SMG5409 (by Secos) is also a surface-mount MOSFET. Sometimes China/Taiwan/Korea clones have an off-by-one number relative to the original. But in this case it doesn't look like I can find anything plausible that way.

Comment: @Gonzik Yes, pad+trace are pretty intact, over 10oz copper! please check http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146160/repair-fixing-back-lifted-power-thru-hole-padtrace

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I haven't. I'll have to dismount it, I was waiting for some feedback here... but that's a good idea. I'll do it in a few hours and post back any finding

Comment: Best guess I could come up with would be possibly some un-listed device from this Chinese company: http://www.sino-mostech.com/ShowProducts.asp?id=49

Comment: @justing Yes, nice suggestion. I've sent them an email, so far no reply.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I've dismounted the replacement unit, but it is heavily epoxied and there is no easy access to the part. I'll buy a dentist mirror monday and see if I can read the markings.

Comment: I can't believe this whole great unit may be down because there is no reference of a FET!!?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I got to the (mosfet) part of the replacement unit, and it has the same markings! I am completely out of ideas! How can I know a component that doesn't show up in google??!!

Comment: @justing Silly me: just saw the manufacturer on PCB back: Formosa Audio, please see new picture at post. However, no success yet: there is no way of contacting them but an email, and there is no response!! Any ideas, guys??

Comment: @RespawnedFluff please check above, maybe it pops some new ideia in your mind ;)

Comment: The fact that the PCB maker is an Asian company which sells their own audio products tells me that they likely designed the board, so it's likely to use Asian-sourced components as well. justing's bet above doesn't look unreasonable. It's sometimes very hard to find any info on such components. I had a similar question which I eventually deleted because of some drive-by downvoting (with no comments...) and not much of a chance of an actual definitive answer.

Comment: By the way, your board might be http://www.taiwantrade.com.tw/EP/formosaaudio/products-detail/en_US/580702/1000W_8_Ohm_digital_subwoofer_plate_amplifier/ but that doesn't help with idenfitying the components.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Exactly, this is the board!! At last a step forward finding something! Tks! But you are right, no component identification. I found this: http://www.taiwantrade.com.tw/EP/resources/member/10405/productcatalog/570d06c3-58b6-4623-adcb-d61b409f79fd_20110525HD11028PA.pdf , there is a phone # I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: No reply from the email address indicated there. It is indeed  probably an Asian component, untraceable by usual googling. Now, if that calling them ultimately fails, I was wondering if there is anyway to estimate the MOSFET/BTJ/IGBT characteristics from the (good) replacing unit. With an oscilloscope, I can have gate drive frequency and levels. Adding a shunt and I can have estimated current levels. Although the plate is heavily epoxied and I had no plans to dismount and unsolder the only good unit I have, it may be an option. What do you think?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I can't say that is exactly the same model as my board. If you check here https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http://formosaaudio.en.b2b168.com/&usg=ALkJrhgHKOd0IABR43-14ky7tdnk9F6OJw , models HD-2504K and HD-2304K are just alike the unit inside my plate...

Answer (score 2):

If you see G,D and S is likely to be a MOSFET, not a BJT. So this is a precious indication and you are very lucky to find it because these markings are very rare. The other good news is that it's 10 years old, not too new and not too old.

Two things you must find out:

1. Voltage on the D pin or, on the S pin if D is ground or the low side. And vice versa. You can check the  voltage rating of the capacitors which are connected to it, if any. And use the same or higher for the MOSFET. If you can't know the voltage, use 300V or more.
2. The maximum current which could possibly go through the MOSFET between D and S. This is more difficult. If you know the voltage, it can't be more than 1000W divided by the voltage on D or S (depending which one is not the low side). So take the highest value available.

The absolute maximum voltage rated for G in the datasheet will likely to be same on every MOSFET you will find. Still, check that it's not lower than 20V (You never know).
(always read the datasheet pdf before buying)

Frequency shouldn't be an issue with modern MOSFETs. That's why 10 years old is a good age. Any newer MOSFET will be better than the original, granted that you can find the same specification or better.
I would even advise NOT to try to find the exact original part since it failed...

Attention: The same model can be fabricated in different packages: D-PAK or something else but the THT variant is often available. Check the datasheet for the exact product code (the last letters define the package, usually). Don't discard or select a model based on the picture on the vendor website.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody out there still searching and trying to identify this part.

i have contacted one reputable electronics components seller from aliexpress and i go this response:
[image]

As you can clearly read it, the component original part no was ITCHED AND ERASED By formosa the company OEM manufacturer of the subwoofer plate amplifier INTENTIONALLY To prevent anyone from repairing their products if they fail.

SMS5408 Is not the actual part no, there's absolutely no part carries that part no, its just an attempt from formosa company to fool anybody who wishes to repair their unit that there are NO AVAILABLE SPARE PARTS Which is false because its actually available.

i reviewed this YouTube video as well and in the comments, one person mentioned that the part is not MOSFET BUT ACTUALLY AN IGBT !!!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgn7xR92H3M

So the GDS Markings on the board ARE ALSO WRONG AND JUST AN ATTEMPT TO MISLEAD ANY PERSON Who wishes to carry out a repair, i have contacted the person who wrote the comment as well as the video poster but with no replies.

Conclusions:
BOTH THE SMS5408 PART NO AND BOARD GDS Markings ARE NOT CORRECT AND INTENTIONALLY IMPLEMENTED THERE TO MISLEAD ANY PERSON AND MAKE THEM GOES IN CIRCLES AND NEVER FIND A SOLUTION.

Bottom line:
the board needs to be reversed engineered by someone who have an in depth knowledge of electronics circuits and their design to figure out the characteristics of those parts and figure out a substitute replacement parts which is simply beyond my knowledge.

hopefully someone out there with the initiative and enough solid scientific background can help one day

Comment: Hi, despite the odds, I'll ask it: can you or your contact share any source about this at all?

Answer (score -1):

One possibility for a 5408 is the military grade of the old 7408 TTL IC, but that's normally in a 14-pin DIP package instead of having only 3 pins.

Comment: I'm not sure how a 14-pin DIP would be useful for replacing a 3 pin component...

Comment: Well , the first main issue is to know what is the SMS 5408 and its specs - I still don't know these information, but I still have the PSU hoping to fix it someday... So why would I replace it for a 7408, even if it would fit, if I don't know what it is for sure?

Comment: The 5408 I was referring to is a TTL chip containing four AND gates.  Very unlikely to be used in a PSU.